# Matplotlib: consistent image size for publications

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to make publication-quality plots with Matplotlib. The biggest problem I am having right now is to tune the image and font sizes.

When I create a figure with several panels, I usually set a bigger `figsize`. For example, these three panels are created with a `figsize=(12, 6 / 1.618)` (pasted from Jupyter Lab, I always save to PDF files).

[image: big-figsize]

The lines can be perfectly seen, there is a lot of space, the figure seems nice. The problem is that in my publication this has to be a column-wise figure, so it has to be scaled down. A colum has a width of around ~3.5 inches. When the image is resized, it still looks good, but the axes labels become very tiny and unreadable. Of course, I can just simply start increasing the font sizes until I find a good size, but I would like to have a workflow that allows me to work with the lengths and sizes I have to use.

When I set the image size to `figsize=(columnw, 0.5*columnw / 1.618)` (so the aspect ratio is the same) as before, and set the font size around 10 (the font size of my publication) this is what I get:

[image: small-fontsize]

So now the fonts are exactly the size I want them to be, the figure does not have to be reescaled, but the contents of the graph seem to be compressed into a very very tiny space. It just look... ugly.

Then, my question is: **why using a big `figsize` with extremely large fontsizes gives a beautiful, readable figure when scaled, but with the a priori correct `figsize` without rescaling seems to be ugly? How could I work with real figsizes from the very beginning to obtain something nice?**

I read some questions regarding image size with Matplotlib on this site, as well as a pair of blog posts, but I haven't found any information regarding this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Linewidths are specified in display coordinates, and as a consequence their absolute width does not change when changing the size of a figure or zooming in or out. Hence when making a very small figure, you need to decrease the linewidth to preserve the relative thickness to other plot elements such as labels. You may then also need to save the plots with a higher DPI such that the lines remain visible in the saved figure.